# What are singletons?? how to use them?? and why to use them?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singleton: How should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used)

hello. i want to know what a singleton is? how to use it? and why do i have to use it. thank you very much. if anybody can give examples with the explanation i would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815528/how-to-answer-the-interview-question-what-is-a-singleton-and-how-would-you-use

Comment: Congratulations, you made a step in the right direction by asking "why".

Comment: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/

Comment: @jose:  One word:  DONT.  Singletons are usually the wrong thing.  A crutch for lazy programmers that brings with it many new problems.

Comment: so if i dont use them. what can i do to be sure that only one instance of a class will be created??.

Answer (score 3):

If you need only a single instance of an object, then you use singleton. It is one of the many standard design patterns.

Let me clarify with a piece of code -

```
public class SingleInstance
{
    private static final SingleInstance OnlyInstance = new SingleInstance();   // Or Any other value

    // Private constructor, so instance cannot be created outside this class
    private SingleInstance(){};

    public static getSingleInstance()
    {
        return OnlyInstance;
    }
}
```

Since this class's constructor is private, it cannot be instantiated in your application, thus ensuring that you have exactly one instance of class `SingleInstance`.

Use this pattern when you need to ensure only one instance of a particular class is created within your entire application.

To learn more, go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: -1:  NO.  If you need only one instance of an object, then **freaking only instantiate it once**!  Singletons are Bad for a number of reasons enumerated elsewhere.

Comment: -1 your example code is not `c++`

Comment: @John Dibling: Could you please provide the link? It would be a great help.

Comment: @Sayem:  There are a bunch already in this thread.

Comment: @Sayem:  Here's another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: @Sam Miller: I didn't notice the C++ tag earlier, sorry.